# random string generators overwriting each other

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and am writing a little webapp that, among other things, generates random strings (used for visualisation, doesn't need to be perfectly random).

The site consists of three divs, which each should generate a random string. On pageload, the divs display 20 hyphens as visual placeholders. Within each div I then want to replace one hyphen after the other with a random character, waiting 100ms between each iteration.

I got this working just fine with one div. But as soon as I do this with multiple divs, each randomly generated character gets immediately overwritten by the almost simultaneously randomly generated character in the following div.

I also added a console.log, so you can see that initially, each div generates a random character, but then the third div overwrites the character in the two other divs.

I'm assuming this is something I'm just not getting yet, so my question:

**How can I keep this from happening, so that each div keeps its own string (and why is this happening in the first place)?**

Thanks for your help, let me know if you need anything else!

```js
const placeholderLength = 20;
let valueForm = [],
  valueModus = [],
  valueInhalt = [],
  placeholder = [];
let valueJoined;

const outputForm = document.getElementById("outputForm");
const outputModus = document.getElementById("outputModus");
const outputInhalt = document.getElementById("outputInhalt");

const randomCharacter = () => {
  const characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ";

  return characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
};

const initialValues = (value, destination, identifier) => {
  let i = 0;
  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      value[i] = randomCharacter();
      valueJoined = value.join("");
      destination.innerHTML = valueJoined;
      i++;
      if (i < placeholderLength) {
        loop();
      }

      console.log(identifier, valueJoined);
    }, 100);
  };
  loop();
};

const main = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < placeholderLength; i++) {
    placeholder.push("-");
  }
  valueForm = valueModus = valueInhalt = placeholder;

  initialValues(valueForm, outputForm, "value 1");

  initialValues(valueModus, outputModus, "value 2");

  initialValues(valueInhalt, outputInhalt, "value 3");
};

main();
```

```css
.output {
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Random Values</h1>
  <h2>Value 1</h2>
  <div id="outputForm" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 2</h2>
  <div id="outputModus" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 3</h2>
  <div id="outputInhalt" class="output"></div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Also, have you tried to use a **local** variable for `valueJoined` such that not all instances of that method use the **same** joined variable?

Comment: Your `valueJoined` is a global variable which exists only once. So of course this is overwritten in any iteration of the loop. Move `valueJoined` inside your loop, as i don't see the need for making it global

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've tried putting the function calls within main into a setTimeout, but that just resulted in the same thing happening with a delay: https://jsfiddle.net/01zpjdh6/2/

I also put valueJoined inside the loop, but the issue persists, unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the same `placeholder` array to all three generators. Since arrays are objects and objects are passed (and assigned) by reference, after this line:

```
valueForm = valueModus = valueInhalt = placeholder
```

...they will point to the same array object. Mutating that object will change it for each generator.

To solve the issue, remove that line:

```js
const placeholderLength = 20;
let valueForm = [],
  valueModus = [],
  valueInhalt = [],
  placeholder = [];
let valueJoined;

const outputForm = document.getElementById("outputForm");
const outputModus = document.getElementById("outputModus");
const outputInhalt = document.getElementById("outputInhalt");

const randomCharacter = () => {
  const characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ";

  return characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
};

const initialValues = (value, destination, identifier) => {
  let i = 0;
  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      value[i] = randomCharacter();
      valueJoined = value.join("");
      destination.innerHTML = valueJoined;
      i++;
      if (i < placeholderLength) {
        loop();
      }

      console.log(identifier, valueJoined);
    }, 100);
  };
  loop();
};

const main = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < placeholderLength; i++) {
    placeholder.push("-");
  }
  //valueForm = valueModus = valueInhalt = placeholder;

  initialValues(valueForm, outputForm, "value 1");

  initialValues(valueModus, outputModus, "value 2");

  initialValues(valueInhalt, outputInhalt, "value 3");
};

main();
```

```css
.output {
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Random Values</h1>
  <h2>Value 1</h2>
  <div id="outputForm" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 2</h2>
  <div id="outputModus" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 3</h2>
  <div id="outputInhalt" class="output"></div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

To assign hyphens to the arrays, you can clone the array (e.g. by using `Array#slice()`):

```js
const placeholderLength = 20;
let valueForm = [],
  valueModus = [],
  valueInhalt = [],
  placeholder = [];
let valueJoined;

const outputForm = document.getElementById("outputForm");
const outputModus = document.getElementById("outputModus");
const outputInhalt = document.getElementById("outputInhalt");

const randomCharacter = () => {
  const characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ";

  return characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
};

const initialValues = (value, destination, identifier) => {
  let i = 0;
  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      value[i] = randomCharacter();
      valueJoined = value.join("");
      destination.innerHTML = valueJoined;
      i++;
      if (i < placeholderLength) {
        loop();
      }

      console.log(identifier, valueJoined);
    }, 100);
  };
  loop();
};

const main = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < placeholderLength; i++) {
    placeholder.push("-");
  }
  
  valueForm = placeholder.slice();
  valueModus = placeholder.slice();
  valueInhalt = placeholder.slice();

  initialValues(valueForm, outputForm, "value 1");

  initialValues(valueModus, outputModus, "value 2");

  initialValues(valueInhalt, outputInhalt, "value 3");
};

main();
```

```css
.output {
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Random Values</h1>
  <h2>Value 1</h2>
  <div id="outputForm" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 2</h2>
  <div id="outputModus" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 3</h2>
  <div id="outputInhalt" class="output"></div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

You can also move the slicing part to the `initialvalues` function, you don't have to repeat yourself:

```js
const placeholderLength = 20;
let valueForm,
  valueModus,
  valueInhalt,
  placeholder = [];
let valueJoined;

const outputForm = document.getElementById("outputForm");
const outputModus = document.getElementById("outputModus");
const outputInhalt = document.getElementById("outputInhalt");

const randomCharacter = () => {
  const characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ";

  return characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
};

const initialValues = (originalValue, destination, identifier) => {
  let i = 0;
  const value = originalValue.slice()
  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      value[i] = randomCharacter();
      valueJoined = value.join("");
      destination.innerHTML = valueJoined;
      i++;
      if (i < placeholderLength) {
        loop();
      }

      console.log(identifier, valueJoined);
    }, 100);
  };
  loop();
};

const main = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < placeholderLength; i++) {
    placeholder.push("-");
  }
  valueForm = valueModus = valueInhalt = placeholder;

  initialValues(valueForm, outputForm, "value 1");

  initialValues(valueModus, outputModus, "value 2");

  initialValues(valueInhalt, outputInhalt, "value 3");
};

main();
```

```css
.output {
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Random Values</h1>
  <h2>Value 1</h2>
  <div id="outputForm" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 2</h2>
  <div id="outputModus" class="output"></div>
  <h2>Value 3</h2>
  <div id="outputInhalt" class="output"></div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```